# mov byte [esi +9], bl causing segfault

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, shellcode

Any idea why this is causing a segfault?  mov byte [esi +9], bl

I went through it line by line using the debugger and they segfault appears after it executes that line.

Which I guess means its trying to access something in memory that its not suppose to.

Here is the whole code:

```
global _start

section .text

_start:

    jmp short call_shellcode


shellcode:

    pop esi

    xor ebx, ebx
    mov byte [esi +9], bl
    mov dword [esi +10], esi
    mov dword [esi +14], ebx

    lea ebx, [esi]

    lea ecx, [esi +10]

    lea edx, [esi +14]

    xor eax, eax
    mov al, 0xb
    int 0x80



call_shellcode:

    call shellcode
    message db "/bin/bashABBBBCCCC"
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the text section is not writeable, and the data section is not executable.

Comment: Thanks!! What would I need to change to fix the segfault?
I don't have a data section, and in the text section, I'm actually writing to esi and not necessarily the text section.